# SQL date range query from two columns(start_date and end_date)

Tags: sql

I have two columns in my table start_date and end_date and my query inputs two values input_start_date and input_end_date.

I want the data from input_start_date to input_end_date by querying start_date and end_date.

I am able to achieve this by following query:

```
    SELECT * FROM table-name where ( 
    (start_date >= input_start_date and end_date <= input_end_date) or
    (start_date <= input_start_date and end_date >= input_end_date) or
    (start_date >= input_start_date and start_date <=input_end_date) or
    (end_date >= input_start_date and end_date <= input_end_date)
);
```

Is there any better way of doing it ?

Comment: Please add some Code what you are trying to do.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: I am using mysql 5.5. I know its pretty outdated. But it will take time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column-names
  FROM table-name
 WHERE column-name BETWEEN value1 AND value2
```

This one is for between one date

```
SELECT column-names
  FROM table-name
 WHERE start_date = input_start_date AND end_date = input_end_date
```